# Trying to set cron property of @Scheduled from property file using @Value but getting compile time error

Tags: java, spring, cron, spring-scheduled

I've been trying to set the cron property of @Scheduled as below.

```
public class ObjectScheduler {
  @Value("${config.cron.expression}")
  private static final CRON_EXPRESSION;

  @Scheduled(cron = CRON_EXPRESSION, zone="GMT")
  public void scheduledObjectFetch() {...}
}
```

I'm getting a compile time error here saying

```
The value for the annotation attribute Scheduled.cron attribute must be a constant expression.
```

The same thing works if I give the expression in the attribute directly

```
@Scheduled(cron = "${config.cron.expression}", zone="GMT")
```

Here also the value is being assigned at runtime from the config so why doesn't it give a compile time error here? Why is it that when I assign it to a variable using the @Value annotation does it not consider it be a constant expression? Is there something I'm missing? Is it due to Java or Spring's @Value annotation?

Answer (score 1):

Spring does not insert `@Value` into static fields though it can be done via a setter.

And this is also applied to `static final` fields which need to be defined at compile time.

So you could not configure `CRON_EXPRESSION` via `@Value`, it could work only if you set it hardcoded:

```
private static final String CRON_EXPRESSION = "0 0 8 * * ?";

@Scheduled(cron = CRON_EXPRESSION, zone="GMT")
  public void scheduledObjectFetch() {...}
```

Comment: Is there a way to set it via properties file by keeping it configurable rather than hard coding it?

Answer (score 1):

In your case you made the field as `final` the most fundamental reason you are not able to inject value into the field using the `@value` is that Java replaces static final "variable" occurrences in the code with the actual values (since it's of course known at compile time). So if you remove the `final` qualifier it should work for you using spring `setter` injection. You cannot use @value to inject value from a property file into a `static final` variable, it's beccause of how java handles final static variables.

Ideally we could use the **spring expression** to populate cron from the `property` file by providing it like :

```
@Component("scheduledAnnotationObjectScheduler")
public class ObjectScheduler {
  @Scheduled(cron = "${cron.expression}")
  public void scheduledObjectFetch() {...}
}
```

**application.properties**

```
cron.expression=0 15 10 15 * ?
```

This should resolve the `cron` value from the property file in theory since it is picked up during component scanning.